# Laravel Migrate not creating all table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to create all of the tables. But Amount table was not created while migrating. is my problem right or wrong? Or why I am fetching this kind of error.  here is my all migration code is
**user **

```
<?php
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

   class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

**Year_month**

```
<?php
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

  class YearMonth extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('year_months',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('ym_id')->primary();

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('year_months');
}
}
```

**Meal Storage**

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

  class MealStorage extends Migration
   {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('meal_storages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('ym_id');
        $table->foreign('ym_id')->references('ym_id')->on('year_months')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('member_id')->on('members')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->integer('meal');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('meal_storages');
}
}
```

**Member**

```
<?php

     use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

  class MealStorage extends Migration
    {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('meal_storages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('ym_id');
        $table->foreign('ym_id')->references('ym_id')->on('year_months')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('member_id')->on('members')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->integer('meal');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('meal_storages');
}
}
```

**amount**

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

 class Amount extends Migration
    {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('amounts',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('member_id')->on('members')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->date('date');

    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('amounts');
}
   }
```

*is that my process right or wrong *
[when I migrate I am fetching this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PQyO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PQyO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you got this error because you try to run member migration twice
check your migration if you have tow migration for this table try ro delete one or if you using a library check maby the have same migration too

Comment: how can I check the migration number? where can I find it?

Comment: Yes  | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table                  | 1     |
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table        | 2     |
| Yes  | 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table            | 2     |
| Yes  | 2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table | 2     |
| Yes  | 2022_07_17_140324_year_month                          | 2     |
| Yes  | 2022_07_17_141306_meal_storage                        | 2     |
| No   | 2022_07_17_141643_member                              |       |
| No   | 2022_07_17_142928_amount